# Reflected dunder method doesn't work for instances of the same type

Tags: python, class, python-class

Here is a small repro - class A and B are exactly the same, with the dunder method implemented for the reflected right shift operator. So, `x >> y` is expected to resolve to `y.__rrshift__(x)`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        
    def __rrshift__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.x + other.x)

class B:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        
    def __rrshift__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.x + other.x)
```

However, the dunder method doesn't work on instances of the same class.

```
A(1) >> A(2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'A' and 'A'
```

While it works for instances from different classes.

```
A(1) >> B(2)

<__main__.B object at 0x7f6ca8294f40>
```

This was pretty surprising. And seems to be common behavior across other reflected operators too (like, `radd`). Is there a reason this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [doc states](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=radd#object.__radd__), it works when operands are of different type

> These functions are only called if the **left operand does not support the corresponding operation** and the operands are of **different types**

---

It seems you only need `__rshift__` in both classes (only in A is valid for your examples)

```
def __rshift__(self, other):
    return self.__class__(self.x + other.x)
```

Comment: Thank you, just came across the documentation too after posting the question. I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: azro: Did you mean `__rrshift__`?

Comment: @martineau that's the one used by the OP. `__rshift__` is enough and working

Comment: @martineau - sorry. I did read the documentation but somehow glossed over it.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs (section [3.3.8. Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) in the Python Language Reference Manual):

> These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation [[3]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#id10) and the operands are of different types. [[4]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#id11)

where [footnote 4](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#id11) reads:

> [4] For operands of the same type, it is assumed that if the non-reflected method – such as `__add__()` – fails then the overall operation is not supported, which is why the reflected method is not called.

So, like it or not, the behavior is intended and documented.

Comment: Thanks, it is documented indeed. Weird I couldn't find anything the previous 30 mins before posting the question.